# Retrieving a sum of a left joined table in c# entity query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got an EF query and in the query I get data from the parent table, and potentially data from 3 child tables, they are left joined.

The parent has a 1 to many relationship with one of the child tables. I am trying to get the count of the number of children rows in the table

```
var exhibitorContentItems = await (from contentitems in _dc.ContentItems.AsNoTracking()
                            join itemcategory in _db.ContentItemCategories.AsNoTracking() on contentitems.ContentItemGuid equals itemcategory.ContentItemID into joinedCatItem
                            from itemcategory in joinedCatItem.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join category in _db.ContentCategories.AsNoTracking() on itemcategory.ContentCategoryID equals category.ContentCategoryID into joinedCat
                            from category in joinedCat.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join association in _db.ContentAssociations.AsNoTracking() on contentitems.ContentItemGuid equals association.ContentItemID into joinedAssoc
                            from association in joinedAssoc.DefaultIfEmpty() // want number of records in association
                            where contentitems.AccountID == session.AccountId 
                            && contentitems.StatusID == (int)DbRowStatus.Enabled
                            select new DataTypes.ViewModels.Content.ContentGridItemViewModel()
                            {
                                 AccountId = contentitems.AccountID,
                                 ContentItemGuid = contentitems.ExhibitorContentItemGuid,
                                 DisplayName = contentitems.DisplayName,
                                 MobileAvailability = contentitems.MobileAvailability,
                                 FileType = contentitems.Filetype,
                                 CategoryName = category.CategoryName ?? "",
                                 ContentItemUrl = contentitems.ContentItemUrl,
                                 AssignedToNumberDevices = association.Count() // what to put here?
                            }).ToDataSourceResultAsync(request);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just using Navigation properties instead of joining?

Comment: Since you want the count, remove the `from`..`in`...`DefaultIfEmpty()` and just put in `joinedAssoc.Count()` in the `select`. Having the `from` statement unrolls the `joinedAssoc` and runs the `select` once per `joinedAssoc` row.

Comment: @NetMage will that not make the join an inner? This child table is optional so I still need valid rows to be returned when they are not in joinedAssoc

Comment: The `into` phrase on the `join` makes it a `GroupJoin` e.g. a join that returns a collection of matching records, which can be empty (hence, `DefaultIfEmpty()` which replaces the empty collection with an empty row). So, if there are no matching records, `joinedAssoc.Count()` would be `0`, but `joinedAssoc.DefaultIfEmpty().Count()` would be `1`. IOTW, the LINQ `into` is like a SQL `LEFT JOIN` with a `GROUP BY`.